# How do I add a noindex meta tag to error report pages.

Tags: php, magento, error-handling, seo, noindex

In Magento there are the generic error reports under /errors. These are currently getting indexed by Google. I tried adding the meta noindex tag to the /default/page.phtml but this did not seem to work. Perhaps I should even be touching these files. In other instances, such as with the wishlist, I updated the XML - but can't work out how to do it in this instance. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following into your `robots.txt` in the website root:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /errors/
```

Also here is a more thorough version if you are interested:

http://www.byte.nl/blog/2012/06/11/magento-robots-txt/